# Search/Filter functionality with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript so trying have some code which contains python elements from for loop and I am trying to create a filter functionality with JavaScript:

Input:

```
  <div class="">
    <input class=""  type="text"  onkeyup= "myFunction()" spellcheck="false" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search fund with keyword">

    <button type="submit" >
      Search
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Python code:

```
{% for fund in funds %}
<div id="fundName" >
  <div class="">
      <h1 class="">
        <a class = '' href="{{url_for('discovery_bp.funds', fund_id=fund['fund_id']) }}"> {{fund['fund_name']}}</a>
      </h1>
      <ul class="">
          <strong>Round title : TBC </strong>
            <li>Deadline : TBC</li>
        </ul>

    <p id="fundDescription" class="">  {{fund['fund_description']}}</p>

  <hr class="">
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

It might sound like a silly question but very new to JavaScript world so wondering if this is correct since it is not doing anything when filtering?

Input:

```
<html lang="en" "><head>
  </head>

<div class=">
  <h1 class=""><label class="" for="weight">
     Fund search
    </label>
  </h1>
  <div class="">
    <input class="" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" spellcheck="false" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search fund with keyword">

    <button type="submit" class="">
      Search
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Python iteration spits out data:

```
<div id="fundName" class="">
  <div class="">
      <h1 class="">
        <a href="/round/harry-s-breakfast-fund"> Harry's breakfast fund</a>
      </h1>
      <ul class="">
          <strong>Round title : TBC </strong>
            <li>Deadline : TBC</li>
        </ul>

    <p id="fundDescription" class="">  An example fund designed to supply.</p>

  <hr class="">
<div id="fundName" class="">
  <div class="">
      <h1 class="">
        <a class="" href="/round/ram-s-get-fit-feb-fund"> Ram's Get Fit Feb fund</a>
      </h1>
      <ul class="">
          <strong>Round title : TBC </strong>
            <li>Deadline : TBC</li>
        </ul>

    <p id="fundDescription" class="">  An example fund designed to supply.</p>

  <hr class="">
<div id="fundName" ">
  <div class="">
      <h1 class="">
        <a  href="/round/funding-service-design"> Funding Service Design</a>
      </h1>
      <ul class="">
          <strong>Round title : TBC </strong>
            <li>Deadline : TBC</li>
        </ul>

    <p id="fundDescription" class="">  An example fund for testing</p>

  <hr class="">
</div>
```

Function:

```
<script>


  function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, h1, div, a, p, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("search");
      filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
      div = document.getElementById("fundName");
      h1 = div.getElementsByTagName("h1");
      
      for (i = 0; i < h1.length; i++) {
          a = h1[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
          txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              h1[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              h1[i].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please remember that [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Remember to separate your concerns: python is what the server runs to generate the page data your users ask for. By the time JS runs on the page in the browser, however the server generated the page data is no longer relevant, only the HTML/JS the browser received is. So: instead of showing a text dump of what the page looks like, for JS what matters is what the DOM tree looks like.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I added inspected page. Would this help?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a whitespace in your content while using a.textContent, you should try trimming the content or simply use a.innerText. Also it seems like your filter is just hiding the heading and not the block of content which I believe might be your intention.

Comment: Tried no luck. Thank for replying! I just added the inspected HTML. Does this help?

Comment: div = document.getElementById("fundName"); will always select the first div which means the filter is not looping over all the H1 tags, you can try changing it to a logic using classes.

Comment: Also your html is not properly nested. Make sure all DIVs are properly nested.